# How to Create trigonometric curves and dashed lines for circle and line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

first of all I want to create this image:

[image: 1]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=1.5cm,y=0.8cm]
        \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
        \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
        \draw[-,thick,domain=-.2:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,\x) node[right] {\footnotesize $$};
        \draw[-,thick,domain=-.2:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,-\x);
        
        % Circle
        \draw[fill=white!40] (0.5,0) circle [x radius =.3 , y radius =0.5];
        \draw[fill=blue!40] (3.3,0) circle [x radius =.3 , y radius =3.249489743];
        \draw[fill=white!20] (3.3,0) circle [x radius =.13 , y radius =3.249489743];
        \draw[fill=blue!40] (4.5,0) circle [x radius =.3 , y radius =4.449489743];
        
        \draw[<->] (3.3,3.7) -- (4.5,4.9) node[above, midway]  {\footnotesize $l$};
        \draw[<->] (3.7,0) -- (3.7,3.249489743) node[right, midway]  {\footnotesize $y_{1}$};
        \draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {\footnotesize $x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[below right]{\footnotesize $y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]

1. I want to create the trigonometric curves, I think it is sin2x + cos^2 x or something.. Instead of just a line y=x and y=-x that will create a cone.
2. Is my trick to create two circles for the middle part good enough? Is there a better method to create the middle part with two circle and white in the middle?

Comment: Hello, concerning 1. you can plot any function with the correct domain and formula as a path:  `\draw[-,thick,domain=-55:50,samples=100] plot (\x,{sin(2*\x)+(cos(\x))^2});`   but the function you gave isn't the one you need https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0i2onunbmz. check the doc for tizk plot https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots

Comment: You can also approximate the plot via Bézier's curves https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.3

Comment: I add this line: `\draw[-,thick,domain=0:5,samples=10] plot (\x,{sin(2*\x)});` or your suggestion, it is only a straight line. Is it the canvas size problem?

Comment: I try to plot `x  + 2 cos x` with Julia it shows a curve that I want, but with tikz this line `\draw[-,thick,domain=0:10,samples=10] plot (\x,{(\x) + 2*(cos(\x)) });` gives straight line... what is wrong with this?

Comment: the question is about sin waves frequency. any sin func can be defined by : `A sin (2 pi f t+ phi) `. A is the amplitude, pi is 3.14.. f is the frequency, t is time (x in the case of a plot) and phi is the phase at the origin.

Comment: you can modify you sin (cos) waves by modifying f and phi. `\draw[-,thick,domain=0:5,samples=100] plot (\x,{sin(25*2*3.14*\x)-(cos(25*2*3.14*\x))^2-\x});` i also added/subbed `x` to have the sin wave rise/lower.

Comment: Done, I have added an answer

Comment: nice, I amma keep guiding you to find the final form. Remember the last complex diagram you posted here and I answered? can you reuse anything from that?

Comment: Which last complex diagram? The one I answer below? like Church Bell..

Comment: This one, @Freya, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670107/how-to-create-annotations-with-curly-brackets-in-tikz

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with. There are better ways to do it but it looks fine:

The hardest part is to fill the cyan tube segment.

To answer your question, I am pasting my comment from above

> The question is about sin waves frequency. Any sin func can be defined by: A sin (2 pi f t + phi). A is the amplitude, pi is 3.14.. f is the frequency, t is time (x in the case of a plot) and phi is the phase at the origin. You can modify you sin (cos) waves by modifying f and phi:
>
> ```
> \draw[-,thick,domain=0:5,samples=100] 
> plot (\x, {sin(25*2*3.14*\x)-(cos(25*2*3.14*\x))^2-\x});
> ```
>
> I also added/subbed x to have the sin wave rise/lower.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=1.5cm,y=0.8cm]
    \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
    \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
    
    \draw[name path = A ,-,thick,domain=0:4.501,samples=100] plot (\x,{sin(25*1*3.14*\x)+(cos(5*1*3.14*\x))^2+\x});
    \draw[name path = B, -,thick,domain=0:4.501,samples=100] plot (\x,{-sin(25*1*3.14*\x)-(cos(5*1*3.14*\x))^2-\x});


%   \draw[dashed] (0.1,-1.1) arc (-90:90:0.17 and 1.1);% half circle facing left
%   \draw(0.1,-1.1) arc (-90:90:-0.17 and 1.1);% 
    
% circle left
    \path[name path = up1] (0,0) -- (0,5);
    \path[name intersections= {of = {up1 and A}, by =p1}];
    \draw let \p1=(p1) in (0,0) circle [y radius=\y1, x radius =\y1/6] ;

%% circle mid
%   \coordinate (y0) at (2,0);
%   \path[name path = up2] (y0) -- (2,11);
%   \path[name intersections= {of = {up2 and A}, by =p2}];
%%  \draw let \p1=(p2) in (y0) circle [y radius=\y1, x radius =\y1/6] ;
%
%   
% circle before 
    \coordinate (y1) at (1.9,0);    
    \path[name path = up3] (y1) -- (1.9,11);
    \path[name path = down3] (y1) -- (1.9,-11);
    \path[name intersections= {of = {up3 and A}, by =p3}];
    \path[name intersections= {of = {down3 and B}, by =p3s}];
    \draw let \p1=(p3) in (y1) circle [y radius=\y1, x radius =\y1/6] ;

    
% circle after 
    \coordinate (y2) at (2.1,0);    
    \path[name path = up4] (y2) -- (2.1,11);
    \path[name path = down4] (y2) -- (2.1,-11);
    \path[name intersections= {of = {up4 and A}, by =p4}];
    \path[name intersections= {of = {down4 and B}, by =p4s}];

% fill mid cone:
\fill[cyan,opacity=0.3] let \p1=(p3) in   (p3) --(p4) --  (p4s) -- (p3s) arc (-90:-270:\y1/6 and \y1) -- cycle  ;
    \draw [fill=white]let \p1=(p4) in (y2) circle [y radius=\y1, x radius =\y1/6] ;
%
    \draw[<->] (y2) -- (p4) node[right, midway]  {\footnotesize $y_{1}$};

% circle  
    \coordinate (y3) at (4.5,0);    
    \path[name path = up5] (y3) -- (4.5, 7);
    \path[name intersections= {of = {up5 and A}, by =p5}];
    \draw let \p1=(p5) in (y3) circle [y radius=\y1, x radius =\y1/6] ;

    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Axis and Delta x
\draw[<->] ($(p3)+(0,0.25)$) -- ($(p4)+(0,0.25)$) node [above]  {\footnotesize $\triangle x_{i}$};
\draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {\footnotesize $x$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I could have used axis symmetry to get the bottom part: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119914/can-we-mirror-a-part-in-tikz-axial-symmetry-reflection

Comment: Your diagram looks very clean.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with asymptote. You can test with http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and/or use the `asymptote` package In the doc asymptote.pdf Chapter 7: LaTeX usage.

[image]

**THE CODE**

```
    //http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
    //
    //Basic settings
    settings.prc=false;
    settings.render = 8;

    import solids;
    currentprojection = perspective(3,2,6,up=Y);
    unitsize(4cm);// it will be necessary to enlarge to scale 4 the text

    // the axes
    draw((0,0,0)--(11,0,0), blue,L=Label(scale(4)*"$x$", position=EndPoint),arrow=Arrows3(5mm)); //x-axis
    draw((0,0,0)--(0,5,0), green,L=Label(scale(4)*"$y$", position=EndPoint),arrow=Arrows3(5mm)); //y-axis
    draw((0,0,0)--(0,0,5), red,L=Label(scale(4)*"$z$", position=EndPoint),arrow=Arrows3); //z-axis
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    triple pO=(0,0,0);
    path3 gene=
    (0,1,0)..(4.5,3,0)
    ..(5.5,2.5,0)
    ..(8,4,0)
    ..(10,4.5,0);
    //   We place two points on the generatrix
    triple p1=point(gene, 1);
    triple p2=point(gene, 1.1);
    // We define a projection on the x axis
    transform3 pr=planeproject(Y,O);
    triple pp1=pr*p1;
    triple pp2=pr*p2;


    // We define and draw the surfaces of revolution
    revolution sur=revolution(pO,gene,X,0,360);
    draw(surface(sur),surfacepen=material(yellow+opacity(0.5)));
    //
    path3 ray=(0,0,0)--(0,1,0);
    revolution disque=revolution(pO,ray,X,0,360);
    draw(surface(disque),yellow+opacity(0.5));
    //
    path3 delta=(p1)--(p2);
    revolution surdelta=revolution(pO,delta,X,0,360);
    draw(surface(surdelta),surfacepen=material(blue));

    //We define two points to display the label delta xi
    triple ph1=pp1+(0,3.5,0);
    triple ph2=pp2+(0,3.5,0);
    //
    draw (p1--ph1,bp+dashed);
    draw (p2--ph2,bp+dashed);
    // The text is enlarged to scale 4
    draw (Label(scale(4)*"$\Delta x_i$",position=MidPoint,align=N),ph1--ph2,2bp+blue);
    draw(Label(scale(4)*"$y_i$",position=MidPoint,align=E),p2--pp2,2bp+dashed+red,arrow=Arrows3(5mm));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the equation of your curve so this is an approximation, but highly customizable.

I am drawing circles. This way is easy to place the points of tangency wherever you want. But as the circles are viewed as ellipses with the perspective, I change the xscale.

The first part is to place all the points. For each circle we need the center, and points of tangency. And we need then in polar coordinates, so we'll know the angels for the tangency.

The rest: a couple or arcs and curves like

```
(A1) to[out=\aa-90,in=\ab+90] (B1) ...
```

The above code draws a curve that leaves the point (A1) with an angle `\aa-90` (tangent to the first circle) and arrives at (B1) with an angle `\ab+90` tangent to the second circle.

The full example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,xscale=0.5]
% DIMENSIONS AND COORDINATES
% first circle from the left
\def\xa{0}   % position
\def\ra{1}   % radius
\def\aa{95}  % angle
\coordinate (A0) at (\xa,0);             % center
\coordinate (A1) at ($(A0)+( \aa:\ra)$); % tangent point above
\coordinate (A2) at ($(A0)+(-\aa:\ra)$); % tangent point below
% second circle
\def\xb{6}   % position
\def\rb{2}   % radius
\def\ab{80}  % angle
\coordinate (B0) at (\xb,0);             % center
\coordinate (B1) at ($(B0)+( \ab:\rb)$); % tangent point above
\coordinate (B2) at ($(B0)+(-\ab:\rb)$); % tangent point below
% third circle
\def\xc{6.5} % position
\def\rc{1.9} % radius
\def\ac{80}  % angle
\coordinate (C0) at (\xc,0);             % center
\coordinate (C1) at ($(C0)+( \ac:\rc)$); % tangent point above
\coordinate (C2) at ($(C0)+(-\ac:\rc)$); % tangent point below
% fourth circle
\def\xd{13}  % position
\def\rd{2.9} % radius
\def\ad{80}  % angle
\coordinate (D0) at (\xd,0);             % center
\coordinate (D1) at ($(D0)+( \ad:\rd)$); % tangent point above
\coordinate (D2) at ($(D0)+(-\ad:\rd)$); % tangent point below
% DRAWING
% section
\fill[cyan!10] (B1) to[out=\ab-90,in=\ac+90]  (C1) arc (\ac:-\ac:\rc)
                    to[out=270-\ac,in=90-\ab] (B2) arc (-\ab:\ab:\rb);
\fill[cyan!60] (C1) to[out=\ab-90,in=\ac+90]  (B1) arc (\ab:360-\ab:\rb)
                    to[out=270-\ab,in=90-\ac] (C2) arc (360-\ac:\ac:\rc);
% first circle
\draw         (A1) arc (\aa:360-\aa:\ra);
\draw[dashed] (A1) arc (\aa:-\aa:\ra);
% rest of the circles
\foreach\i/\j in {B/\rb,C/\rc,D/\rd}
  \draw (\i0) circle (\j);
% surface
\draw[thick,cyan] (A1) to[out=\aa-90,in=\ab+90] (B1) to[out=\ab-90,in=\ac+90]
                  (C1) to[out=\ac-90,in=\ad+90] (D1);
\draw[yscale=-1]  (A2) to[out=\aa-90,in=\ab+90] (B2) to[out=\ab-90,in=\ac+90]
                  (C2) to[out=\ac-90,in=\ad+90] (D2);
% axis
\draw[thick]  (-\ra,0) --++ (-1,0);
\draw[dashed] (-\ra,0) --   (D0);
\draw[thick]  (D0)  --   (\xd+\rd+1,0);
\foreach\i in {A,B,C,D}
  \fill (\i0) ellipse (0.8mm and 0.4mm);
% labels
\draw[latex-latex]            (C0) --++ (0,\rc)     node[midway,right] {$y_1$};
\draw         (B0) ++  (0,\rb+0.1) --++ (0,1);
\draw         (C0) ++  (0,\rc+0.1) --++ (0,1+\rb-\rc);
\draw[-latex] (B0) ++ (-0.5,\rb+1) --++ (0.5,0);
\draw[-latex] (C0) ++  (0.5,\rb+1) --++ (-0.5,0);
\draw         (B0) ++    (0,\rb+1) --++ (\xc-\xb,0) node[midway,yshift=3mm] {$\Delta x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=1.5cm,y=0.8cm]
        \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
        \fill[fill=white,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
        
        \draw[-,thick,domain=0:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,{sin(25*1*3.14*\x)+(cos(5*1*3.14*\x))^2+\x});
        \draw[-,thick,domain=0:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,{-sin(25*1*3.14*\x)-(cos(5*1*3.14*\x))^2-\x});
        
        % Circle
        \draw[dashed] (0.1,-1.1) arc (-90:90:0.17 and 1.1);% half circle facing left
        \draw(0.1,-1.1) arc (-90:90:-0.17 and 1.1);% 
        
        \draw[fill=blue!40] (2,0) circle [x radius =.7 , y radius =3.2];
        \draw[fill=white!20] (2,0) circle [x radius =.33 , y radius =3.2];
        \draw[fill=blue!40] (4.5,0) circle [x radius =.3 , y radius =4.449489743];
        
        
        \draw[<->] (2,3.5) -- (2.4,3) node[above, midway]  {\footnotesize $\triangle x_{i}$};
        \draw[<->] (2,0) -- (2,2.8) node[right, midway]  {\footnotesize $y_{1}$};
        \draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {\footnotesize $x$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: ohh looks so pretty! now you want to change those bluish circles in to hollow looking tubes?

Comment: You already made the hollow looking tubes. I am happy with this code I made. Thanks!